# Google bots redirecting to admin login page and not indexing the site

Tags: google-search-console

I've been submitting my website to the search console for a month. So far, only one keyword has been ranked. When I checked the url Inspection tool to see why this is the case, only the Google Bot WordPress login page crawled. I understand that other pages (such as Homepage, About Us) do not crawl.  I read a lot of articles related to this and tried to solve the problem. sitemap, robot.txt, cache clearing, etc. Received in the search console. Yet there is no progress. They also could not see an error when talking to the server support.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

[image]

Please note: there is no error showing in search console like security, coverage errors.

Bing webmaster tool crawling and working as normal

Comment: I'm not sure that is the login page.   In many WordPress themes, there is a login form on every page.

Comment: `/wp-admin/` does not prompt users to create an account to log into a website. That has to be a prompt from another service.

Comment: I realize that, there is hidden front end login content in my theme script.